# How do i snap 2 path points together in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, path

I simply want to combine the 2 selected points shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, points on one path cannot be joined with points on another path, unless you need to merge the paths themselves into a single shape, in which case you can do as seen below in green.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop there's no need for mathematically exact snap. Zoom in so that you can see single pixels of a bitmap image. Move your nodes well inside the same pixel. Everything where the paths are actually used in Photoshop images such as stroked paths, filled subpaths or selections work like the nodes were exactly in the same place.

Here's 2 paths with not so well to the same place inserted corner points. The black square is a colored actual pixel:

[image]

Filling the paths with different colors make this in Photoshop:

[image]

Anti-aliasing makes the shapes much more fuzzy than how much the nodes were misplaced. In normal watching zoom the result is well acceptable:

[image]

In vector graphics programs exact node snaps are implemented because poor placement itroduces easily harmfully visible errors when parts are combined or clipped with each other. If exact snaps are a must, edit your paths in Illustrator. They can be moved between the programs.

If it happens that you are in a hurry and want to avoid zooming you can use guides. Place to the snapping point a vertical and a horizontal guide. Keep View > Snap > to guides = ON and place the nodes exactly. Unfortunately the guides must be there at first and both nodes should be snapped to them. Instead of guides you can have a grid and place everything with it. Have View > Snap > to grid =ON.